# text flowing out of border in pdf

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I have created a pdf using tcpdf in php. i have a table with one row and one column. when i put the content from a form which is a textarea, the content in the form flows out of the table border. how can i make it so that it is contained in the border itslef???

Answer (score 0):

Which method do you use for writing the table?
On TCPDF website there is example no.48, where I see line breaks working well:
http://www.tecnick.com/pagefiles/tcpdf/example_048.pdf
http://www.tecnick.com/pagefiles/tcpdf/example_048.phps

They use writeHTML:
http://www.tecnick.com/pagefiles/tcpdf/doc/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html#methodwriteHTML

Two of many reasons why line-breaking does not work could be:

1. There are non-breaking spaces in the text (like `&nbsp;`)
2. You have not specified cell width.
3. When you say 'content from a form which is a textarea', do you mean you add textarea to the input? That is wrong. I think they don't support it.